# C# - Pass result of builder into lambda

Tags: c#, builder

Is it possible to use the resulting object of a builder inside a builder method lambda? Like this:

More specifically, let's say I have classes:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int MyProp { get; set; } 
    public IBar FoosBar { get; set; }

    public Foo(Bar bar) => FoosBar = bar;

    public bool Check() 
    {
        int result = FoosBar.DoThis();
        return result < MyProp;
    }
}

public interface IBar 
{
    public int DoThis(int value);
}

public class AnonymousBar : IBar 
{
    private Func<int, int> _doer;

    public AnonymousBar(Func<int, int> doer) => _doer = doer;
    public int DoThis(int value) => _doer(value); 
}
```

My builder looks like this:

```
public class Builder 
{
    private IBar _bar;

    public Builder WithBar(Func<int, int> doer)
    {
        _doer = new AnonymousBar(doer);
        return this;
    }

    public Build() => new Foo(_bar);
}
```

And using my builder I can do:

```
Foo myFoo = new Builder().WithBar(i => 7).Build();
```

Is it possible to modify `AnonymousBar` so that I can do something like:

```
Foo myFoo = new FooBuilder().WithBar(foo => foo.MyProp % 12).Build();
```

where `foo` is `myFoo`, so that `myFoo.Bar.DoThis()` uses `myFoo.MyProp`?

> Ignore the implementation logic. I know it's nonsensical. This is just an example.

Comment: You don't have `Bar` defined anywhere, did you mean to use `IBar` inside of `Builder` and `Foo`?  Also `_doer` is not defined in `Builder` either, was that suppose to be `_bar`?

Comment: @juharr Yes. I'll update my post.

Comment: Also you can do `public int DoThis(int value) = > _doer(value);` or at least you need to do `_doer.Invoke(value);`

Comment: Oh and `Builder` instead of `FooBuilder`.

Comment: The implementation details don't matter as much. That's already worked out. I'm just interested on getting the built `Foo` into `AnonymousBar.DoThis()`.

Comment: You want the `Foo` created by `Build` to be passed into the `foo => foo.MyProp % 12` lambda?  If so `IBar` isn't sufficient for that.  You'd need a `int DoThis(Foo foo)` and `Foo` would need to know to use that instead.

Comment: Also you cannot call `FooBar.DoThis()` as it is because it takes an `int` argument.

Comment: Where is that `Foo` coming from?

Comment: Fixed the problems with `Func`.